# Drive API children.list q parameter broken

Tags: google-drive-api

The query string in try it section does not work 12 hours ago.
My query string is ***mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'***
Anyway not work with any query.
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list
Please tellme why??

Comment: I can confirm that the API is NOT working. Here is a sample call that demonstrates the problem. All queries using the "q" parameter appear broken: go to https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list, at the end on Try it, enter folderid=0B-P6m1j2b6F4Mm5rc1QyTXNuYTA, q=hello, authenticate and run the query. RESULT: lists everything, regardless of what you put on "q". this is VERY serious!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue:

```
child.Q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and title contains 'SomeDocuments'"
Dim cl As ChildList = child.Fetch
```

it returns all the documents like there was no filter

Maybe something change on Google Drive API?

**Update**
I can't find anything from Google, I wrote a feedback in the child list page.
The only workaround so far is instead of using the children.list use the file.list method and in the q section add the - 'folderid' in parents - search term to emulate searching on childrens of the parent folder.
The drawback is it will only search for document that has folderid as parent, not sub-folders like children.list method do.

**Update 2**
Looks like Google fixed it!
Happy coding.

Comment: Google Drive API is still misbehaving for me here in Australia.  This thread http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/O_A3tb-aAVM is about the same issue.